# Create dict with key/value and key/value reversed

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

Having such list

`example = ['ab', 'cd']`

I need to get `{'a': 'b', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'c'}`

With regular loop I could do this like:

```
result = {}
for i,j in example:
    result[i] = j
    result[j] = i
```

Question: How can I do the same on one line?

Comment: `dict(example + [s[::-1] for s in example])`

Comment: @vaultah, please write it as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
dict(example + [s[::-1] for s in example])
```

`[s[::-1] for s in example]` creates a new list with all strings reversed. `example + [s[::-1] for s in example]` combines the lists together. Then the `dict` constructor builds a dictionary from the list of key-value pairs (the first character and the last character of each string):

```
In [5]: dict(example + [s[::-1] for s in example])
Out[5]: {'a': 'b', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension with dictionary updates

```
[result.update({x[0]:x[1],x[1]:x[0]}) for x in example]
```

Comment: `for x in example:result.update({x[0]:x[1],x[1]:x[0]})` is cleaner.

Comment: you would still need a logical line for `result={}`

Answer (score 0):

A [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) should do:

```
In [726]: {k: v for (k, v) in map(tuple, example + map(reversed, example))}  # Python 2
Out[726]: {'a': 'b', 'b': 'a', 'c': 'd', 'd': 'c'}

In [727]: {s[0]: s[1] for s in (example + [x[::-1] for x in example])}  # Python 3
Out[727]: {'b': 'a', 'a': 'b', 'd': 'c', 'c': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `;` to seperate logical lines

```
result=dict(example); result.update((k,v) for v,k in example)
```

But of course

```
result=dict(example+map(reversed,example)) # only in python 2.x
```

or

```
result=dict([(k,v) for k,v in example]+[(k,v) for v,k in example])
```

work, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
example = ['ab', 'cd']

res1={x[1]:x[0] for x in example}
res2={x[0]:x[1] for x in example}
res=res1.update(res2)
print res1
```